# OS compatibility for SDL 8.1

Tags: web8, sdl-tridion

Is SDL Web-Build 8.1.0.194 compatible with Windows Server 2019? I am upgrading the OS to Windows Server 2019 in which I have SDL 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.rws.com/792468/108949/sdl-web-8--retired-/content-manager-server-prerequisites), only Windows Server 2012 R2 and 2008 R2 SP1 are supported.

Windows 2008 support ended a few years ago, and Windows Server 2012 will reach end of life later this year... so, I think the answer to your question is "No".

To upgrade the OS you will need to upgrade Tridion as well. While it *may* work with Windows 2019, there are zero guarantees that this is the case, and RWS support will be unable to help you as this is not a supported version.